# Problem with updating date from form to database

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to update date_of birth column in database and when I submit my form I get this error

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (25/03/1995) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

Now in my blade I formated date of birth to show d/m/Y and when updating I think it updates Y/m/d, because when I remove format function from my blade it works fine. So I need help on how to update with format('d/m/Y') in my database and how to validate it properly in my form request validation. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

index.blade.php

```
<input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="date_of_birth" value="{{ $userForShowProfile->date_of_birth ? $userForShowProfile->date_of_birth->format('d/m/Y') : "" }}">
```

UserController.php

```
public function updateProfileCharacteristics(UpdateProfileCharacteristicsRequest $request)
{
     $user = Auth::user();

     $user->update(
     [
        'date_of_birth' => $request->date_of_birth,
        'age' => Carbon::now()->diffInYears($request->date_of_birth),
        'updated_at' =>  Carbon::now()
     ]
     );

     return redirect()->route('profile.show', [$user->username]);
}
```

UpdateProfileCharacteristicsRequest.php

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'date_of_birth' => ['date'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Clarification: `format()` function just works on Carbon object, is `$userForShowProfile->date_of_birth` a Carbon object?

Comment: Illuminate\Support\Carbon @638323200  this I get when I dump it. So yes it is. It formats it nicely in blade, but when I try and update it then I get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sending the date in a custom format in the request, you will need to parse it to a format that matches the one in the database column before inserting it:

```
 $user->update(
 [
    'date_of_birth' => Carbon::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $request->date_of_birth)->format('Y-m-d'), // parse the right format here
    'age' => Carbon::now()->diffInYears(Carbon::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $request->date_of_birth)),
    'updated_at' =>  Carbon::now()
 ]
 );
```

And for that date format to pass validation you can use the `date_format:format` rule instead of `date`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'date_of_birth' => ['date_format:"d/m/Y"'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the column type in you database migration? If it is check if it DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, It is supposed to be DATE hence you can format your date to be Y-m-d.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Ok try to cast in you user model.    protected $casts = [
        'date_of_birth' => 'date',
    ];   and check here for more info https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (25/03/1988) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character          vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php:81 and on line 81 is        parent::__construct($time ?: 'now', static::safeCreateDateTimeZone($tz) ?: null);

Comment: If you are to save a DATE to DB it should be in the format of  Y-m-d. so try this      
public function updateProfileCharacteristics(Request $request)
{
     $user = Auth::user();

     $user->update(
     [
        'date_of_birth' => Date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->date_of_birth)),
        'age' => Carbon::now()->diffInYears($request->date_of_birth),
        'updated_at' =>  Carbon::now()
     ]
     );

     return redirect()->route('profile.show', [$user->username]);
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are to save a DATE to DB it should be in the format of  Y-m-d.

so try this:

```
public function updateProfileCharacteristics(Request $request)
{

   $user = Auth::user();

   $user->update([
        'date_of_birth' => Date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->date_of_birth)),
        'age' => Carbon::now()->diffInYears($request->date_of_birth),
        'updated_at' =>  Carbon::now()
     ]);

     return redirect()->route('profile.show', [$user->username]);
}
```